# Proving big O notation statement

Tags: algorithm, big-o, proof

Ok Im a bit new and my mathematical proof knowledge and practice is novice will, its not much as I'm only a few weeks into an algorithm and design paper and am a little learning challenged. I am trying to wrap my head around a several lab question questions and I'm hoping that if someone can help me with this I will build a little momentum and be able to answer the harder ones under my own steam.

I have a **definition**: Let f, g be functions. If there exist c, n0 > 0 such that,for all n > n0, f(n) ≤ c · g(n), then f(n) is O(g(n))

Have to prove this using the definition.

For every function **f : N→N, f(n) is O(f(n)).**

Now firstly I'm confused bu the face that g(n) isnt in this question but it is in the harder ones so I know it isnt a typo. I'm thinking that it is the same function so shouldn't it be big theta? I am very confused. Also how to present this as a proof is also quite mysterious to me. Can I do this as a direct proof?

Most appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, I think your question is better suited for: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or rather: [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Pedantically, the definition should demand that `f : N -> N` and that `c` is positive. It might be clear from the overall context, but the requirement for the definition is somewhat unspecific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are puzzled by the fact that the statement you are trying to prove uses only one function, namely `f`, while the definition you quote involves two different functions.

That being said, the statement you are trying to prove is that every function from `N` to `N` does not asymptotically grow *faster than itself*, what is not so surprising. For a formal proof, let `f : N -> N` be such a function.

Let `c := 1` and `n0 := 0`; let `n` be an integer such that `n > n0`. Then we obtain

```
f(n) = 1 * f(n) = c * f (n) <= c * f (n)
```

which, by definition, means that `f in O(f)`, which was the statment to be proved.

This is a direct proof which is carried out by explicit choice of `c` and `n0` from the definition and showing that they satisfy the condition from the definition.

As this is apparently a homework question, I suppose it is given as an example to introduce the formal definition and how to work with it, and not so much because the statement itself is interesting.